# nest.js and cloudinary: problem with single image upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, cloudinary

I am trying to upload user's avatar to cloudinary, so far the function looks like this:

```js
uploadStreamFile(file: Express.Multer.File): Promise<CloudinaryResponse> {
    return new Promise<CloudinaryResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
      const uploadStream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) return reject(error);
          resolve(result);
        },
      );

      streamifier.createReadStream(file.buffer).pipe(uploadStream);
    });
  }
```

**It works**, but my goal is to save the image and overwrite it if user will change avatar again. In [cloudinary docs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_and_video_upload) I found upload function that can take my desired options, so I modified function to:

```js
  async uploadFile(file: Express.Multer.File, userId: string) {
    console.log(`FILE: ${file}`)
    console.log(`FILE NAME ${file.filename}`)
    console.log(`ORG NAME ${file.originalname}`)
    console.log(`FIELD NAME ${file.fieldname}`)

    const uploadResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.originalname, {
    folder: 'avatars',
    public_id: userId,
    overwrite: true, 
  });
```

and the output:

```bash
649439028425fb78cabf8601
FILE: [object Object]
FILE NAME undefined
ORG NAME 103_gargamel.jpg
FIELD NAME file
[Nest] 62390  - 07/01/2023, 9:33:00 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Object:
{
  "error": {
    "errno": -2,
    "code": "ENOENT",
    "syscall": "open",
    "path": "103_gargamel.jpg"
  }
}
```

I think request from frontend is ok, because file and userId are passed successfully.
As first argument I tried to pass "avatar" (instead of file.originalname) or even binary buffer, but TS is expecting string there.

In case someone needs, this is the controller:

```js
 @Post('upload/:userId')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    uploadImage(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File, @Param('userId') userId: string)
    {
      return this.cloudinaryService.uploadFile(file, userId);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `ENOENT` means the file not found, you're passing the file name, but the file is probably not saved to disk so when cloudinary upload function tries to find it - it can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Multer setup is correct(as it seems), you can do the following to convert incoming image to base64 and then send it as data URI, as it's suggesting in [the docs(...a base64 data URI...)](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_and_video_upload#node_js_image_upload):

```js
  async uploadFile(file: Express.Multer.File, userId: string) {
    const imageAsBase64 = file.buffer.toString('base64');
    const dataURI = `data:text/plain;base64,${imageAsBase64}`;

    const uploadResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(dataURI, {
    folder: 'avatars',
    public_id: userId,
    overwrite: true, 
  });
```

I'd also suggest looking at [this article](https://thecodeway.hashnode.dev/streamline-your-file-uploads-with-cloudinary-and-nestjs#heading-single-file-upload) and using streams instead:

```js
async uploadFile(
  file: Express.Multer.File,
): Promise<UploadApiResponse | UploadApiErrorResponse> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    v2.uploader.upload_stream(
      {
        resource_type: 'auto',
      },
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(result);
      }
    ).end(file.buffer)
  })
}
```